How to estimated balance changes by web3.py
I am simulating the information obtained before the interaction between the wallet and the contract in the figure below through web3.py. I want to obtain the Gas fees and benefits before the actual transaction through simulated transactions. Gas fees are already available. However, the income circled in the picture cannot be obtained through web3.py and is displayed as empty.
Can anyone tell me how to use web3.py to obtain benefits similar to those obtained after the wallet simulates transactions? thanks.

import requests
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()

RPC_URL = os.getenv("RPC_URL")
wallet_address = os.getenv("ACCOUNT_ADDRESS")
api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")


contract_address = "0xxxxxxx"

# Basescan API URL
api_url = f"https://api.basescan.org/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={contract_address}&apikey={api_key}"


response = requests.get(api_url)
response_json = response.json()


if response_json['status'] == '1' and response_json['result'] != '0':
    contract_abi = json.loads(response_json['result'])
else:
    print("Error fetching ABI:", response_json['message'], response_json['result'])
    exit()



web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(RPC_URL))


if not web3.is_connected():
    print("Failed to connect to Ethereum network")
    exit()


contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)


def estimate_gas(function_call):
    try:
        
        transaction = {
            'from': wallet_address,
            'to': contract_address,
            'data': function_call._encode_transaction_data(),
        }
        gas_estimate = web3.eth.estimate_gas(transaction)
        print(f"Estimated Gas: {gas_estimate}")
        return gas_estimate
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error estimating gas: {e}")
        return None


def simulate_transaction(function_call):
    try:
        simulation_result = function_call.call({'from': wallet_address})
        print(f"Simulation Result: {simulation_result}")
        return simulation_result
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error simulating transaction: {e}")
        return None


def estimate_and_simulate(function_name):
    if hasattr(contract.functions, function_name):
        function_call = getattr(contract.functions, function_name)()

        
        print(f"Method Name: {function_name}")

        
        gas_estimate = estimate_gas(function_call)
        if gas_estimate is None:
            print("Gas estimation failed.")
            return

        simulation_result = simulate_transaction(function_call)
        if simulation_result is None:
            print("Transaction simulation failed.")
            return

        print(f"Estimated Gas: {gas_estimate}")
        print(f"Simulation Result: {simulation_result}")
    else:
        print(f"Function {function_name} not found in contract.")


function_name = "harvest"  
estimate_and_simulate(function_name)




Think either write a custom contract that returns the info you want and eth_call it (simple cheap way), otherwise use geth debug namespace (or equivalent for other EVM clients) and set up tracers (usually on your personal node). https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/developers/evm-tracing/basic-traces | https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-debug#debug_tracetransaction

OK thank you. I'll try it and ask you if I have any questions.

You can

Use Anvil to create a forked blockchain
Then broadcast the transaction against your private fork (any state changes will be memory only)
Parse token balance changes from the generated ERC-20 Transfer events


Thanks. But I don’t want to fork the blockchain, but call it through the main network static simulation. It seems that the debug_tracCall method is used to obtain it. After all, the wallet will not fork the blockchain every time to gain profits.Can you tell me how to use debug_tracCall.？

As in the screenshot, wallet security simulations do indeed use forked blockchains under the hood. Unfortunately, this is the shit you get on the Ethereum and its design flaws. If you do not like there, there are better blockchans that can achieve the functionality directly without hacks. You can try to do a debug_traceCall but it is likely going to be even more difficult. Forked blockchain and tx is the easiest way to get ERC-20 events required for incoming and outgoing token transfers.

OK thank you. I'll try it and ask you if I have any questions.
